# Disable messages upon loading a package

Tags: r, message, libraries, suppress-warnings, verbosity

I have a package in R (ROCR) that I need to load in my R environment.  Upon loading the package, a set of messages are printed.  This is ordinarily fine, but since the output of my R script is being used for further analysis I want to completely disable all of this output.  How do I do that?  Furthermore, I'd prefer to do it without having to modify ROCR at all, so that future users of this script don't have to do that either.

So far:

- `sink()` doesn't work here - redirecting both stdout and std err to `/dev/null` does nothing for me.
- Unsurprisingly, `options(warnings=-1)` does nothing either, since these are not warnings, per se, being printed.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What messages are being printed?

Comment: While the entire output is unnecessary, the first several lines are:                  `Loading required package: gplots
    Loading required package: gtools
    Loading required package: gdata` - Note that it won't let me format the message correctly.

Comment: @Jack, nope, see my answer below for the proper fix.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel - That works too.  TIMTOWTDI.

Comment: No Jack, not really. `suppressMessages()` also suppresses noisy textual message, at least from packages that conform, and protects you against other packages adding new dependencies which you'd need to reflect manually.

Comment: Obligatory "its a package, not a library" comment here

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Just use `suppressMessages()` around your `library()` call:

```
edd@max:~$ R

R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Copyright (C) 2011 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
[...]

R> suppressMessages(library(ROCR))
R>                                               # silently loaded
R> search() 
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"         "package:ROCR"         # it's really there      
 [3] "package:gplots"     "package:KernSmooth"
 [5] "package:grid"       "package:caTools"   
 [7] "package:bitops"     "package:gdata"     
 [9] "package:gtools"     "package:stats"     
[11] "package:graphics"   "package:grDevices" 
[13] "package:utils"      "package:datasets"  
[15] "package:methods"    "Autoloads"         
[17] "package:base"      
R>
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use `suppressPackageStartupMessages`?

Comment: No net gain apart from spending X more characters.  Plus `suppressPackageStartupMessages` suppresses only _startup messages_ where as my preferred `suppressMessages()` suppresses any and all messages (but not `cat()` as I recall).  But one is not supposed to use that in startup text.

Comment: It's also great that Dirk's suggestion suppress messages from depending packages as well when they're being loaded.

Comment: Is there a way to capture those startup messages? I can capture warnings and errors, but don't know how to capture other such messages.

Comment: @Adrian yes there is, wrap into tryCatch and provide message handler

Answer (score 37):

[Dirk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8681811/1613005) suppresses all messages and is not specific to messages that is generated while loading packages.

The more accurate solution to the asked question is:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library("THE_PACKAGE_NAME"))
```

A bit more detailed explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41285354/1613005)

Answer (score 36):

Use [`suppressPackageStartupMessages`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/message.html), see the answer by *MehradMahmoudian*. For completeness, adding here examples of usage:

For one library, use `suppressPackageStartupMessages(...)`, for example:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggplot2))
```

For multiple libraries, use `suppressPackageStartupMessages({...})`, for example:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    library(ggplot2)
    library(ggdendro)
})
```

**SEE ALSO:**
[Suppress package startup messages](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/suppress-startup-messages.html)

Answer (score 3):

`library(ROCR, quietly = TRUE)` might be a more elegant option.

Comment: not really, try `library(data.table, quietly = TRUE)`

Comment: neither `quietly=TRUE` nor `verbose=FALSE` suppress the messages.

Answer (score 2):

If you load packages with a for loop, then you have to silent the complete loop like I show below instead of suppressing the message when loading the library individually.

```
requiredPackages = c('plyr','dplyr','data.table')
suppressMessages(
 for (p in requiredPackages) {
  if (!require(p, character.only = TRUE)){
   install.packages(p)
  }
  library(p, character.only = TRUE)
 }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

By adding `quietly = T` as shown below will solve the issue:

```
suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(library("dplyr", quietly = T)))
```

In case of multiple package you can use :

```
## specify the package names
PKGs <- c("affy","gcrma","readxl","ggplot2","lattice" )
```

and them use lapply as below:

```
lapply(PKGs, library, character.only = TRUE ,quietly = T)
```