# Send messages to file not as expected

Tags: r

Trying to use `message` for some simple logging in RStudio. I would love to have the possibility of messages ending up in a temp file.

After reading this [How can you always suppress messages in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767751/how-can-you-always-suppress-messages-in-r) I thought I knew how to proceed.

```
message("this is red text on screen")

zz <- file("messages.Rout", open = "wt")
sink(file=zz, type = "message")

message("This I hope only goes to the file")

sink(type="message") #Reset so that messages come out to screen as normal
```

Problem is that the text `This I hope only goes to the file` still shows up in the console within RStudio when Current Chunk is Run.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Big thanks in advance, I've been using R for a while but often come back with newbie questions....

Comment: I can't reproduce this error.

Comment: Thanks @David.
Just to confirm, when you run the above "This I only hope goes to the file" is not seen in console in RStudio, but instead ends up in the file.