# prevent testthat from printing unnecessary messages to the console

Tags: r, testthat

I'm setting up tests for my personal R package and I want to minimise the output to the Build console (I'm on RStudio). I'm using `sink` to suppress messages from my own functions (see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767751/how-can-you-always-suppress-messages-in-r)) because they're only relevant in an interactive data analysis context. This is not ideal but it works; any hints as to how to handle that better would be appreciated.

What I haven't managed to eliminate are package attachment messages. My package attaches `tidyverse` and `sf`, which added to `testthat`, means I get a long list of well-known mask warnings and version information. Having `suppressMessages(library(my_package))` (see the highest voted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279808/r-suppress-startupmessages-from-dependency#6279889)) on `testthat.R` doesn't seem to do the trick either.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: What about the `suppressPackageStartupMessages()` function? When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr Flick. `supressMessages` is meant to cover `suppressPackageStartupMessages`. I've added a link to a relevant answer and checked that, indeed, it makes no difference. Sorry, I'm not sure how I can provide a reproducible example of testing a working R package? the mock code as I've written it above works on any standard R script... it doesn't in the `testthat` environment, hence the question. Please do let me know what I can share that would be useful.