# Suppress reader parse problems in r

Tags: r, readr

I am currently reading in a file using the package `readr`. The idea is to use `read_delim` to read in row for row to find the maximum columns in my unstructured data file. The code outputs that there are `parsing` problems. I know of these and will deal with column type after import. Is there a way to turn off the `problems()` as the usual `options(warn)` is not working

```
i=1
max_col <- 0
options(warn = -1)
while(i != "stop")
{
  n_col<- ncol(read_delim("file.txt", n_max = 1, skip = i, delim="\t"))
  if(n_col > max_col) {
    max_col <- n_col
    print(max_col)
  }
  i <- i+1
  if(n_col==0) i<-"stop"
}
options(warn = 0)
```

The output to console that I am trying to suppress is the following:

```
.See problems(...) for more details.
Warning: 11 parsing failures.
row      col   expected  actual
  1 1####4 valid date 1###8
```

Comment: I've the feeling you should fix the file out of R before importing it. Maybe awk is better suited for the task ?

Comment: `suppressWarnings(x <- readr::parse_integer(c("1X", "blah", "3")))` seems to work...

Comment: Probably better to open a `file` connection, read the file a line at a time and count the separators? `max(sapply(readLines("file.txt"),function(x){length(strsplit(x,"\t")[[1]])}))`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In R you can suppress three main annoying things while using packages:

1. messages `suppressMessages(YOUR_FUNCTION)`
2. warnings `suppressWarnings(YOUR_FUNCTION)`
3. package startup messages `suppressPackageStartupMessages(YOUR_FUNCTION)`

So in your case imho also let the package developer knows so that he/she can for example add a `verbose` argument in the function.

Answer (score 8):

if you are using rmd 'R Markdown' with RStudio, you can pass in the following arguments which will suppress the warning messages as well as the columns names.

[image: RMD warning suppress]

````
```{r warning = FALSE, message=FALSE}
````

HTH
AA

Comment: or in your knitr options with knitr::opts_chunk$set(
 message = FALSE,
 warning = FALSE
)