# Ignore trailing delimiters in readr::read_csv()

Tags: r, csv, readr, tidyverse

When I read a CSV file containing a trailing delimiter using `readr::read_csv()`, I get a warning that a new name for the last column was created. Here is the contents of a short example file to show what a mean:

```
A,B,C,
2,1,1,
14,22,5,
9,-4,8,
17,9,-3,
```

Note the trailing comma at the end of each row. Now if I load this data with

```
readr::read_csv("A,B,C,\n2,1,1,\n14,22,5,\n9,-4,8,\n17,9,-3,")
```

I get the following message:

```
New names:
• `` -> `...4`
```

The resulting tibble has an extra fourth column names `...4` consisting of `NA` values in each row:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
      A     B     C ...4 
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
1     2     1     1 NA   
2    14    22     5 NA   
3     9    -4     8 NA   
4    17     9    -3 NA
```

Even if I explicitly load only the first three columns with

```
read_csv(
    "A,B,C,\n2,1,1,\n14,22,5,\n9,-4,8,\n17,9,-3,",
    col_types=cols_only(
        A=col_integer(),
        B=col_integer(),
        C=col_integer()
    )
)
```

I still get this message.

Is this the expected behavior or is there some way to tell `readr::read_csv()` that it is supposed to ignore all columns except the ones I specify? Or is there another way to tidy up this (apparently malformed) CSV so that trailing delimiters are deleted/ignored?

Comment: Can you add a small example that shows the problem?  Does the warning affect the output in some way or is it just a message?

Comment: It is just a warning message, but it seems strange that even with `cols_only` all columns seem to be imported. I edited my question to include a small example CSV file to show the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can. From what I can see in the documentation, `cols_only()` is for R objects that you have already loaded in.

However, the `fread()` function from the `data.table` library allows you to select specific column names as a file is read in:

`DT <- fread("filename.csv", select = c("colA","colB"))`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another example with error message.

```
> read_csv("1,2,3\n4,5,6", col_names = c("x", "y"))
Warning: 2 parsing failures.
row # A tibble: 2 x 5 col     row   col  expected    actual         file expected   <int> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>        <chr> actual 1     1  <NA> 2 columns 3 columns literal data file 2     2  <NA> 2 columns 3 columns literal data

# A tibble: 2 x 2
      x     y
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     4     5
```

Here is the fix/hack.  Also see this SOF link.
[Suppress reader parse problems in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462725/suppress-reader-parse-problems-in-r)

```
> suppressWarnings(read_csv("1,2,3\n4,5,6", col_names = c("x", "y")))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      x     y
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     4     5
```

Comment: This [blog post](http://romainfrancois.blog.free.fr/index.php?post/2009/05/20/Disable-specific-warnings) describes how to catch only specific warnings. Could be useful to only suppress this particular warning.