# (Error) when silencing output for xgboost while performing cross-validation

Tags: r, cross-validation, xgboost

I am performing cross-validation with xgboost in R.  I have a Windows 10 system and am using 3.3.2.  For some of my runs, a number of iterations are required before my early stop requirement has been met.  So, I wish reduce the number of lines spit out in the console.

I have tried `silent=1` which does nothing to silence the output in the console, `verbose_eval=50` which does nothing to limit the output in the console and lastly `verbose_eval=False` which gives the following error message and halts termination:

```
Error in check.deprecation(...) : object 'False' not found
```

I suppose the last one may only be valid in Python and that might be the source of the error.  Still, the other two methods I try do not reduce the output to the console.

My code to show how I am applying these:

```
for (eta in seq(0,1,0.1)) {
    param <- list(objective = "reg:linear", val_metric = "rmse", eta = eta, booster = "dart")
    mdcv <- xgb.cv(param = param, data = sapply(train[1:80], as.numeric),   label = as.numeric(unlist(train[81])), verbose_eval=50, nfold = 10, nrounds = 30000, early_stopping_rounds = 8)
    min_rmse <- mdcv[[4]][mdcv$best_iteration]$test_rmse_mean
    print(paste(eta, ' ', min_rmse))
}
```

Comment: This is a typo. Use FALSE not False. I make the opposite typo often in python.

Comment: @lmo Ah yes, I see.  So, my error disappears, but I am left with similar behavior as the other two options I give.  My output is in no way limited inside the console.

Comment: I don't have access to this package at the moment to look at the options, but you could try wrapping the function in `suppressMessages`.

Comment: @lmo If I do `suppressMessages(library(xgboost))` before the code above, still nothing.  I read at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681688/disable-messages-upon-loading-package-in-r that it does not suppress `cat()`, but I don't know if that is applicable in this case

Comment: Also, I know I could try to use `sink()` and put it to file, but I want to try to figure out why everything is still going to console.