# Suppress loading messages when calling function directly (not loading package in full)

Tags: r

I want to suppress a loading message much like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681688/disable-messages-upon-loading-a-package), except that I am not loading the whole package but calling a function directly.

For example, calling `raster` functions as follows:

```
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster::raster(f)
p <- raster::rasterToPolygons(r, dissolve = TRUE)
```

Results in the message:

```
Loading required namespace: rgeos
```

How can I prevent this message from appearing? The only solution I have found so far is to load `rgeos` as follows:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(rgeos))
```

But as I'm using the function `raster::rasterToPolygons` from within a package I don't really want to load `rgeos` in full.

Comment: Have you tried `p <- suppressWarnings(raster::rasterToPolygons(r, dissolve = TRUE))`?

Comment: If that function requires the package, then the entire package is getting loaded. Are you writing your own package? Did you try listing `rgeos` as a dependency?

Comment: Yes I had listed `rgeos` as a dependency of the package and tried `suppressMessages` but didn't seem to help. Importing `rgeos` in full in the NAMESPACE does the trick though. Seems excessive for the use of one function, but I guess it'll do!

Comment: Sorry, I'm being dim: `suppressWarnings(raster::rasterToPolygons(r, dissolve = TRUE))` doesn't work (it's not a warning message), but `suppressMessages(raster::rasterToPolygons(r, dissolve = TRUE))` *does* work (without importing `rgeos` into the NAMESPACE). Could've sworn I tried that already! Oh well. Will add as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I'd tried this before but apparently not. Both of these options work:

```
p <- suppressMessages(raster::rasterToPolygons(r, dissolve = TRUE))
p <- suppressPackageStartupMessages(raster::rasterToPolygons(r, dissolve = TRUE))
```

I call the function explicitly using `::` (advised by Hadley [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#imports)), but you can also avoid the `rgeos` loading message by importing it in the `NAMESPACE` of your package. If using `roxygen2`, that means adding `@import rgeos` as an `roxygen2` comment at the top of your function. I imagine `@importFrom rgeos fun` would work too, but I don't know which `rgeos` functions are being used by `raster::rasterToPolygons`.