# Load multiple packages in R using Google Colab

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

The question is specific to Google Colaboratory (and the [solution for R in general](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8681688/4089351) doesn't work), and has answers referring to Python, but I am inquiring about R packages, which do work flawlessly in Google Colab, allowing a clean document to be generated with Markdown and code.

Incidentally, Google Colab is absolutely fabulous if you are working behind a firewall blocking the download of R packages - so if you wonder why Google Colab, and not RStudio Markdown, this is **the** one beautiful, magnificent, unsurpassed advantage (in this setting). If you don't understand what I am referring to, you haven't spent time in the corporate world, so don't worry about it (RStudio still the best).

Here is the failed attempt to extrapolate the suggestion on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8681688/4089351) for R (or RStudio) to Google Colab:

```
install.packages('RCurl')
require(repr) 
require(RCurl)
require(foreign)
require(tidyverse)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you also post the code?

Comment: @MathAvengers It is there... Just one line.

Comment: sorry missed that, it's different than what i usually do. umm.. why don't you try loading the packages one by one with `library()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `suppressPackageStartupMessages({...})`

```
install.packages('RCurl')
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    require(repr) 
    require(RCurl)
    require(foreign)
    require(tidyverse)
})
```