# How to silent R when loading libraries in command line?

Tags: r

I am running R 4.0.2 on a mac os 11.2

If I call the following libraries in R studio, this all go silently as expected

```
requiredPackages = c('dplyr','data.table',
                     'stringr','tools',
                     'lubridate','docopt',
                     'geosphere','scales',
                     'rgdal','tidyverse',
                     'stringi')
for(p in requiredPackages){
  if(!require(p,character.only = TRUE)) install.packages(p)
  suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(require(p,character.only = TRUE)))
}
```

But when I copy these lines in a command line R script

```
script.R:

#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
requiredPackages = c('dplyr','data.table',
                     'stringr','tools',
                     'lubridate','docopt',
                     'geosphere','scales',
                     'rgdal','tidyverse',
                     'stringi')
for(p in requiredPackages){
  if(!require(p,character.only = TRUE)) install.packages(p)
  suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(require(p,character.only = TRUE)))
}
```

and run

```
./script.R
```

I get back all the verbose

```
    Loading required package: dplyr

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Loading required package: data.table

Attaching package: ‘data.table’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

    between, first, last

Loading required package: stringr
Loading required package: tools
Loading required package: lubridate

Attaching package: ‘lubridate’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:data.table’:

    hour, isoweek, mday, minute, month, quarter, second, wday, week, yday, year

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    date, intersect, setdiff, union

Loading required package: docopt
Loading required package: geosphere
Loading required package: scales
Loading required package: rgdal
Loading required package: sp
rgdal: version: 1.5-23, (SVN revision 1121)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 3.1.4, released 2020/10/20
Path to GDAL shared files: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rgdal/gdal
GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
Loaded PROJ runtime: Rel. 6.3.1, February 10th, 2020, [PJ_VERSION: 631]
Path to PROJ shared files: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rgdal/proj
Linking to sp version:1.4-5
To mute warnings of possible GDAL/OSR exportToProj4() degradation,
use options("rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings"="none") before loading rgdal.
Loading required package: tidyverse
── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.0 ──
✔ ggplot2 3.3.2     ✔ readr   1.3.1
✔ tibble  3.0.2     ✔ purrr   0.3.4
✔ tidyr   1.1.0     ✔ forcats 0.5.0
── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
✖ lubridate::as.difftime() masks base::as.difftime()
✖ data.table::between()    masks dplyr::between()
✖ readr::col_factor()      masks scales::col_factor()
✖ lubridate::date()        masks base::date()
✖ purrr::discard()         masks scales::discard()
✖ dplyr::filter()          masks stats::filter()
✖ data.table::first()      masks dplyr::first()
✖ lubridate::hour()        masks data.table::hour()
✖ lubridate::intersect()   masks base::intersect()
✖ lubridate::isoweek()     masks data.table::isoweek()
✖ dplyr::lag()             masks stats::lag()
✖ data.table::last()       masks dplyr::last()
✖ lubridate::mday()        masks data.table::mday()
✖ lubridate::minute()      masks data.table::minute()
✖ lubridate::month()       masks data.table::month()
✖ lubridate::quarter()     masks data.table::quarter()
✖ lubridate::second()      masks data.table::second()
✖ lubridate::setdiff()     masks base::setdiff()
✖ purrr::transpose()       masks data.table::transpose()
✖ lubridate::union()       masks base::union()
✖ lubridate::wday()        masks data.table::wday()
✖ lubridate::week()        masks data.table::week()
✖ lubridate::yday()        masks data.table::yday()
✖ lubridate::year()        masks data.table::year()
```

Is there any way to silent a command line script?
I want the script to say when it is missing some input arguments, so I need to get rid of all this fuzzy verbose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable messages upon loading a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681688/disable-messages-upon-loading-a-package)

Comment: Two key takeaways: (1) if all packages did things politely, then `suppressPackageStartupMessages` would work for all packages. (2) Unfortunately, not all packages do that, some instead use `message` or (gasp!) `cat`. To account for those cases, you need to *add* the use of `suppressMessages` and `capture.output`. Yes, that stinks.

Comment: Thanks you both, I ended using suppressMessages(suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(p,character.only = TRUE)))
which cleared all for me.